# Which of the following numbers are the smallest and largest: $\sqrt[5]{2}, \frac{4}{3}, \sqrt[6]{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which of the following numbers are the smallest and largest: $\sqrt[5]{2}, \frac{4}{3}, \sqrt[6]{3}$ ?

I am not supposed to do any calculations with a calculator, any way to see this intuitively?

Thank you!

Comment: intuitively?? I don't think so..

Comment: Without **any** calculations ?

Comment: may be the question asks you not use the calculator for finding the exact number for all the three expressions.

Comment: I am not supposed to use a calculator, and all other questions before it has been more in line of quite simple algebraic manipulations. So I thought that there might be a way to "see" which of the numbers that are the largest and smallest...

Comment: May be you want to replace **do any calculations** by **use calculator**

Comment: Sorry for that Praphulla, I did not mean to cause any confusion. This is corrected now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to doing this without a calculator is that $x^n$ for $n>0$ is a (strictly) monotonically increasing function. Thus $x^n > y^n \Rightarrow x>y$.

This means we can eliminate the roots by raising to the 5th and 6th power. Comparing both numbers first to $4/3 = 2^2/3$ we get

$2<2^{10}/3^5 \Rightarrow \sqrt[5]{2}<4/3$

and

$3^7 < 2^{12} \Rightarrow \sqrt[6]{3}<4/3$

thus the largest number is $4/3$. To find the smallest we raise the two smaller numbers to the power $5\times6 = 30$ giving us $2^6$ and $3^5$ to compare. $2^6 = 64$ and it takes only a few multiplications to see that $3^5$ is indeed the larger so we get

$$\sqrt[5]{2} < \sqrt[6]{3} < \frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation Dan. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: Did you mean
$$
2<2^{10}/3^5 \Rightarrow \sqrt[5]{2}<4/3
$$
and
$$
3^7 < 2^{12} \Rightarrow \sqrt[6]{3}<4/3 ?
$$

Comment: I did indeed. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$2^6<3^5\Rightarrow ???$

$(\frac{4}{3})^2>(1.3)\cdot(1.3)=1.69$

$(\frac{4}{3})^4> (1.6)\cdot(1.6)=2.56$

$(\frac{4}{3})^6> (2.5)\cdot(1.6)=4$

Does this help you ??

Comment: Not really. The OP needs bounds, not approximations. (Also, it looks very odd to approximate $1.69$ as $1.6$.)

Comment: @TonyK : I mean $4<(\frac{4}{3})^6$

Comment: That's much better :-)

Comment: @TonyK : :) ${~~~}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It does help me :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  You can compare $\sqrt[5]{2}$ with $4/3$ by raising each number to its fifth power, $\sqrt[5]{2}$ to $\sqrt[6]{3}$ by raising each number to its $30^{\text{th}}$ power, and $4/3$ to $\sqrt[6]{3}$ by raising each number to its sixth power.

Answer (score 0):

Raise all the numbers to the 6th power:
$$
(\sqrt[5]{2})^6 = \sqrt{2^{12/5}} < \sqrt{2^{12/4}} = \sqrt8 \lt \sqrt{9} = 3
\\(4/3)^6 = (1 +\tfrac{1}{3})^6 > 1 + 6 \times \tfrac{1}{3} = 3
\\ (\sqrt[6]{3})^6 = 3
$$

Answer (score 0):

First raise $4/3$ to various powers to compare that with the radicals. Thus $(4/3)^3=64/27>2$, from which $4/3>\sqrt[5]2$ and $4/3>\sqrt[6]4>\sqrt[6]3$.

We are left with $\sqrt[6]3$ and $\sqrt[5]2$. Instead of raising these to the $30$th power we can more subtly render $3>\sqrt8=2\sqrt2$, from which

$\sqrt[6]3>\sqrt[6]{2\sqrt2}=\sqrt[4]2>\sqrt[5]2.$

So $4/3$ is largest and $\sqrt[5]2$ is smallest.